Is there a way to make a Blazor website fully work offline?
We have a Blazor website made, but the client needs it to work offline.
I need to load all the data necessary when there is internet connection so that i can later use it in the pages. Not just reading the data but also writing new data that would then be synced to the database upon the users request. This solution should work for both mobile and desktop.
Is there a way to make this happen in Blazor? Or would it be easier to use some other tecnology?
I have tried to explore the Blazor WASM PWA, i tried tinkering around with some libraries to use IndexedDb but with little success. Either the library didnt work or there would be a problem getting data.

What library do you use? blazor wasm pwa can work offline.

@QiangFu i tried BlazorDB and Reshiru's. Reshiru's just didn't work at all, BlazorDB i wan'st able to get the data from the IndexedDB

You can google offline web apps to explore the possibilities. Suggesting libraries to you is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow questions. Certainly it is possible to store data for an offline web app - you really should do your own research there too and make a decision on your own. If, on the other hand you have specific code that you can share that you need help with for using IndexedDb with a blazor wasm app, then share that code and describe the problem.

To learn more about this site and how we can help you, please start with the Tour and read How to Ask and its linked resources.

@JoãoRodrigues so the real problem isn't how to work offline, but specific libraries and how they're used. Both of these were abandoned 4 years ago. There are other, fresher libraries

I tried with Tavenem.Blazor.IndexedDB and it works when offline.You could try following steps.
Create a .net8 wasm-standalone pwa project. Modify the "service-worker.js" like below: (I just cache resource when visit 1st time)
const cacheName = `myCache`;
const assetsToCache = [
    '/favicon.png'
];
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    console.log('V1 installing…');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.addAll(assetsToCache))
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    console.log('Cache now ready to handle fetches!');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(cachedResponse => {
            if (cachedResponse) {
                // Return the cached response if found
                return cachedResponse;
            }

            // If the request is not in the cache, fetch from the network
            return fetch(event.request).then(networkResponse => {

                // Open the cache and store the network response
                const responseToCache = networkResponse.clone();
                caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
                    cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                });

                return networkResponse;
            });
        })
    );
});

Install Tavenem.Blazor.IndexedDB
program.cs
builder.Services.AddIndexedDbService();

Home.razor
@page "/"
@using Tavenem.Blazor.IndexedDB
@using Tavenem.DataStorage
@inject IndexedDbService _indexedDbService

abc
<button @onclick="test">test</button>

@code{

    private async Task test(){

        var item = new Item
            {
                Id = "1",
                Value = "Hello, World!",
            };
        var db = new IndexedDb("myDatabaseName",_indexedDbService,1);
        await db["store1"].StoreItemAsync<Item>(item);
    }
    public class Item : IdItem
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}

Reference: https://github.com/Tavenem/Blazor.IndexedDB

I tried using this package but i cannot register the service in the Program.cs, i'm adding this line 'builder.Services.AddIndexedDbService();' But it does not recognize the 'AddIndexedDbService'.

@JoãoRodrigues  I tested with a brand new .net8 WASM template and install Tavenem.Blazor.IndexedDB 4.0.2, then this line is recognized.

dont know what was happening with the project i had create a new one and it works now... But i cannot add items to the indexed db My code looks like this
var db = new IndexedDb("DataGiicLocal", _indexedDbService, 1);
foreach(var c in Clientes)
await db["CLIENTES"].StoreItemAsync(c);
when it reaches the StoreItemAsync it fully crashes the website, no error message or anything
